# Conditional Loops with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

In my code I am trying to use a second loop and it should traverse the array of body mass indices and call another function that accepts the body mass index as a parameter and returns whether the individual is underweight, normal weight or overweight.

Here is where am stuck at. code.....

```
individuals = ["Mike Jackson", "Mike Tyson", "Mike Jordan"]
bodymass = list()
index = 0

def BMI(height, weight):
    bmi = (weight * 703) / (height ** 2)
    return bmi

for individual in individuals:
    print("Do you want to know the BMI for", individual, "?")
    print("The weight is required for", individual)
    weight = eval(input("Enter weight in pounds here:  "))
    print("The height is required for", individual)
    height = eval(input("Enter height in inches for here:  "))
    bmi = BMI(height, weight)
    bodymass.append(bmi)
    print("The body mass index for", individual, "is:  ", (bmi))

for i in range(len(bodymass)):
    if 18.5 > bodymass[i]:
        print("You are underweight.")
    elif 18.5 <= bodymass[i] < 25:
        print("Your weight is normal.")
    elif bodymass[i] >= 25:
        print("You are overweight.")
```

=============================================

Here is the resut...

```
Do you want to know the BMI for Mike Jackson ?
The weight is required for Mike Jackson
Enter weight in pounds here:  175
The height is required for Mike Jackson
Enter height in inches for here:  72
The body mass index for Mike Jackson is:   23.73167438271605
Your weight is normal.
Do you want to know the BMI for Mike Tyson ?
The weight is required for Mike Tyson
Enter weight in pounds here:  184
The height is required for Mike Tyson
Enter height in inches for here:  80
The body mass index for Mike Tyson is:   20.21125
Your weight is normal.
Your weight is normal.
Do you want to know the BMI for Mike Jordan ?
The weight is required for Mike Jordan
Enter weight in pounds here:  215
The height is required for Mike Jordan
Enter height in inches for here:  78
The body mass index for Mike Jordan is:   24.843030900723207
Your weight is normal.
Your weight is normal.
Your weight is normal.

Process finished with exit code 0

=====================================
```

The issue that I am having is for the next person or object that inputs a value, the result from the previous person shows. So by the third person it show 3 values of "You are underweight" instead of the result of just that person.

You are underweight.
You are underweight.
You are underweight.

Answer (score 1):

use code like this.
when you type the weight and height it gives you the BMI and result  for that person
then you type  the information of the next person and again it gives you BMI and result.
code:

```
individuals = ["Mike Jackson", "Mike Tyson", "Mike Jordan"]
bodymass = list()
index = 0

def BMI(height, weight):
    bmi = (weight * 703) / (height ** 2)
    return bmi


def bmi_result(bmi) :
    if 18.5 > bmi:
       print("You are underweight.")
    elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
       print("Your weight is normal.")
    elif bmi >= 25:
       print("You are overweight.")

for individual in individuals:
    print("Do you want to know the BMI for", individual, "?")
    print("The weight is required for", individual)
    weight = eval(input("Enter weight in pounds here:  "))
    print("The height is required for", individual)
    height = eval(input("Enter height in inches for here:  "))
    bmi = BMI(height, weight)
    bmi_result(bmi)
    print("The body mass index for", individual, "is:  ", (bmi))
```

Answer (score 0):

because of (for) function, in each round, all of the results will print;
for fix this problem make a function and type the seccond block of your code in it and in each round of your first (for) func, call this function, like this :

```
def bmi_result(bmi) :
    if 18.5 > bmi:
       print("You are underweight.")
    elif 18.5 <= bmi < 25:
       print("Your weight is normal.")
    elif bmi >= 25:
       print("You are overweight.")
```

use bmi_result(bmi) instead of bodymass.append(bmi)
Goodluck.

Comment: That did not work,it still shows the the last result in the next.

Comment: Your weight is normal.
Your weight is normal.
Your weight is normal.